# The best color to track using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using a program to track object(in my case a pen) using OpenCV c++ code

I want to track the object based on its color and I want to be differentiated from the background easily.

From testing I recognize that the shine color which we call them phosphoric color are more able to be recognized from other objects..
Anybody know the reason why they are more recognizable than other color ?

Comment: Without showing your detection code and maybe some pictures noone will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to track object is to transform the video you get from RGB to HSV

```
//convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
cvtColor(cameraFeed,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

and than use `erode()` and `dilate()` function to avoid disorders.

Than using a certain range of HUE values you can select a range of colors.

There isn't a best color, the important thing is the difference between your object and the background.

[image]

Search for green in the ROI

```
//initial min and max HSV filter values.
//these will be changed using trackbars
int H_MIN = 0;
int H_MAX = 180;
int S_MIN = 0;
int S_MAX = 255;
int V_MIN = 20;
int V_MAX = 50;
//filter HSV image between values and store filtered image to
    //threshold matrix
inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
```

However would be quite useful have your piece of code, just to test what you are saying about shine colours.

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to hsv and then by changing the h,s,v values using trackbars you will get your object and then you can easily track the object.Else you can make use of the contour specialities of the object.